# How should i figure out the exact meaning of such sentence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, floating-point

[There](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#id9) is a confusing description of built-in function `divmod()`,i post below:

> If x is very close to an exact integer multiple of y, it’s possible for x//y to be one larger than (x-x%y)//y due to rounding. In such cases, Python returns the latter result, in order to preserve that divmod(x,y)[0] * y + x % y be very close to x.

`x//y`should be equal to  `(x-x%y)//y` ,according to the identity `x == (x//y)*y`.I wonder how can `x//y` be larger than  `(x-x%y)//y` when rounding occurred.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: It would be better if there is any mathematical proof or explicit explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick "for instance" to explore this corner case, in an Idle shell, I entered:
`x,y=1.0,0.1`

and then:
`x/y;x//y;x%y;x-x%y;(x-x%y)//y;x//y==(x-x%y)//y`.

For most values of x that are multiples of y, the final result is `True` (e.g., for x == 0.1 thru 0.9), but in the case of x == 1.0, it is `False`.

`x,y=0.9,0.1`:

```
9.0
8.0
0.09999999999999998
0.8
8.0
True
```

`x,y = 1.0,0.1`:

```
10.0
9.0
0.09999999999999995
0.9
8.0
False
```